# WSO2 IS 430 - Godaddy SSL Certificate installation fails

Tags: ssl, wso2-api-manager, wso2

I tried installing SSL certificate I purchased from Godaddy (CN = my domain) following below steps. And after the last step I did a GREP search for .jks in repository/conf directory and replaced all keystore configs (wso2carbon.jks) to my JKS and password. Restarted the server. It started giving a bunch of errors and server not started properly.. But when I changed ONLY catalina_server.xml's configuration and undo all others, it started and SSL was working only for 9443 port but when I checked the cert installation from a SSL checker tool, it said cert was not installed properly. And even API gateway endpoints were not working with SSL (browser rejects cert) and it was port 8244. What have I done wrong? Exception trace given below.

1. Create Keystore and the CSR

   ```
    keytool -genkey -alias certalias -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -keystore newkeystore.jks
   ```
2. Create CSR - copy output and submit to Go Daddy.

   ```
    keytool -certreq -alias certalias -keystore newkeystore.jks
   ```
3. Get the Certificates for tomcat you will get below certificates.

   ```
   gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt - Root Certificate
   gdig2.crt.pem - Intermediate Certificate
   [randomNumber].crt - Domain Certificate
   ```
4. Convert crt to pem.

   ```
   openssl x509 -in gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt -out gd_bundle-g2-g1.pem
   openssl x509 -in [randomNumber].crt -out [randomNumber].pem
   ```
5. Join root and intermediate certificate

   ```
    cat gdig2.crt.pem gd_bundle-g2-g1.pem >> clientcertchain.pem
   ```
6. Extract the key from the keystore.

   ```
   keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore newkeystore.jks -destkeystore keystore.p12 -deststoretype PKCS12 -srcalias keys -deststorepass -destkeypass
   openssl pkcs12 -in keystore.p12 -nodes -nocerts -out key.pem
   ```
7. Create pkcs12 keystore

   ```
    openssl pkcs12 -export -out final.p12 -inkey key.pem -in [randomNumber].crt -CAfile clientcertchain.pem -name "cacertificates"
   ```
8. Create JKS from pkcs keystore.

   ```
    keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore final.p12 -srcstoretype PKCS12 -destkeystore wso2carbon.jks
   ```
9. Replace it with wso2carbon.jks located in `<WSO2AM_HOME>/repository/resources/security/`
10. Go to `<WSO2AM_HOME>/repository/resources/security/`
11. Extract key file to add client keystore

    ```
     keytool -export -alias cacertificates -keystore newkeystore.jks -file .pem
    ```
12. Add key to client-truststore.jks

    ```
     keytool -import -alias cacertificates -file .pem -keystore client-truststore.jks -storepass wso2carbon
    ```